# Possible to reduce number of queries from 5 to 1?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a gallery of "Leaders" on my site, where the top users in 5 different categories are selected by a DESC LIMIT 1; the gallery is generated with 5 separate INNER JOIN between the stats and login tables, but all the SELECT clauses are identical:

```
$cat1wins="SELECT stats.login_id, stats.cat1wins, login.user, login.picture,      
login.statement FROM stats INNER JOIN login ON stats.login_id=login.login_id ORDER by 
stats.cat1wins DESC LIMIT 1";

$cat2wins="SELECT stats.login_id, stats.cat2wins, login.user, login.picture,      
login.statement FROM stats INNER JOIN login ON stats.login_id=login.login_id ORDER by 
stats.cat2wins DESC LIMIT 1";

$cat3wins="SELECT stats.login_id, stats.cat3wins, login.user, login.picture,      
login.statement FROM stats INNER JOIN login ON stats.login_id=login.login_id ORDER by 
stats.cat3wins DESC LIMIT 1";

$cat4wins="SELECT stats.login_id, stats.cat4wins, login.user, login.picture,      
login.statement FROM stats INNER JOIN login ON stats.login_id=login.login_id ORDER by 
stats.cat4wins DESC LIMIT 1";

$cat5wins="SELECT stats.login_id, stats.cat5wins, login.user, login.picture,      
login.statement FROM stats INNER JOIN login ON stats.login_id=login.login_id ORDER by 
stats.cat5wins DESC LIMIT 1";
```

For each category, a WHILE loop extracts the proper table cell (shown here with cat1)

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$cat1wins);
WHILE ($Category1Wins = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
$Cat1User = $Category1Wins['user'];
$Cat1Statement = $Category1Wins['statement'];
echo "code"; //etc
}
```

I imagine there must be a better way to do this; I imagine I could start like this:

```
$catAllwins="SELECT stats.cat1wins, stats.login_id, login.user, login.picture,      
login.statement, SELECT stats.cat2wins, stats.login_id, login.user, login.picture, 
login.statement,.....SELECT stats.cat5wins, stats.login_id, login.user, login.picture, 
login.statement FROM stats INNER JOIN login ON stats.login_id=login.login_id";
```

and then use a WHILE loop on the results of each SELECT statement within $catAllwins to generate 5 separate arrays that can then be sorted with a **natsort**. However, I am not sure how to extract the proper SELECT statements. I was thinking I could say something like:

```
$catAllwins="SELECT stats.cat1wins, stats.login_id, login.user, login.picture,      
login.statement AS 'array1', SELECT stats.cat2wins, stats.login_id, login.user,    
login.picture, login.statement AS 'array2',.....SELECT stats.cat5wins, stats.login_id,  
login.user, login.picture, login.statement AS 'array5' FROM stats INNER JOIN login ON 
stats.login_id=login.login_id";

$resultAll = mysqli_query($con, $catAllwins)
$Cat1WinsArray = $resultAll['array1'];
$Cat2WinsArray = $resultAll['array2'];
$Cat3WinsArray = $resultAll['array3'];
$Cat4WinsArray = $resultAll['array4'];
$Cat5WinsArray = $resultAll['array5'];
```

then sort the arrays with **natsort** (one example shown)

```
$SortedCat1WinsArray = natsort($Cat1WinsArray);
```

then add **array_reverse** for descending order:

```
$DescSortedCat1WinsArray = array_reverse($SortedCat1WinsArray);
```

then WHILE this array to extract each component I need (e.g., $row['picture'], $row['login_id'], etc.). Does this sound remotely plausible? I would appreciate any feedback! Is there an easier way?

Comment: What you're looking for is a `UNION`

Comment: Thanks for the edits Cryode....5 to 1 is what I meant. My bad :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just UNION the individual select statements together and apply a sort to the resulting union.  Here is an example:

```
(SELECT stats.login_id, stats.cat1wins, login.user, login.picture, login.statement
FROM stats INNER JOIN login ON stats.login_id=login.login_id
ORDER by stats.cat1wins DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT stats.login_id, stats.cat2wins, login.user, login.picture, login.statement
FROM stats INNER JOIN login ON stats.login_id=login.login_id
ORDER by stats.cat2wins DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT stats.login_id, stats.cat3wins, login.user, login.picture, login.statement
FROM stats INNER JOIN login ON stats.login_id=login.login_id
ORDER by stats.cat3wins DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT stats.login_id, stats.cat4wins, login.user, login.picture, login.statement
FROM stats INNER JOIN login ON stats.login_id=login.login_id
ORDER by stats.cat4wins DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT stats.login_id, stats.cat5wins, login.user, login.picture, login.statement
FROM stats INNER JOIN login ON stats.login_id=login.login_id
ORDER by stats.cat5wins DESC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY /* Whatever you want to sort by. Wasn't clear in the questoin */
```

Comment: and you could use PHP to generate this query with a `for` loop

Comment: @scrowler Certainly, but creating single query on DB would typically be considered a best approach,

Comment: @scrowler Yes. Sorry I guess I didn't read your comment properly.  Absolutely, the query could be built in a loop.

Comment: The UNION operator has a potential to eliminate duplicate rows, the UNION ALL operator doesn't remove duplicates. If there's a need to distinguish the cat1wins row from the cat2wins2 row, then a literal can be included in the select list of each query. (There is no guarantee that the rows will be returned in the order the queries that produced each row, or even that every query will produce a row. )

Comment: OK....thank you. I will try this out right away. Would it be possible to use the AS clause within the UNION query you posted, something like: ....stats.cat1wins DESC LIMIT 1 AS 'Cat1Wins'.....etc, then extract 'Cat1Wins' with mysqli_fetch_assoc or foreach?

Comment: @ChemBlob9999: Not like that, but you could `(SELECT 'Cat1' AS Wins, stats.login_id, ... LIMIT 1) UNION ALL (SELECT 'Cat2', ... )`, and then you'd have that column available to identify which row is which.

Comment: Tried this with UNION and UNION ALL....needed aliases.....worked for first category but second category and on were "blank" (none of the variables could seem to be extracted in my WHILE loop)...I will keep trying...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sorting by five different variables is expensive.  You might find the following approach to be more efficient:

```
select l.login_id,
       (case when s.cat1wins = smax.max_cat1wins then 'cat1'
             when s.cat2wins = smax.max_cat2wins then 'cat2'
             when s.cat3wins = smax.max_cat3wins then 'cat3'
             when s.cat4wins = smax.max_cat4wins then 'cat4'
             when s.cat5wins = smax.max_cat5wins then 'cat5'
         end) as which,
       (case when s.cat1wins = smax.max_cat1wins then s.cat1wins
             when s.cat2wins = smax.max_cat2wins then s.cat2wins
             when s.cat3wins = smax.max_cat3wins then s.cat3wins
             when s.cat4wins = smax.max_cat4wins then s.cat4wins
             when s.cat5wins = smax.max_cat5wins then s.cat5wins
         end) as numwins,
       l.user, l.picture, l.statement,
from stats s inner join
     (select max(stats.cat1wins) as max_cat1wins,
             max(stats.cat2wins) as max_cat2wins,
             max(stats.cat3wins) as max_cat3wins,
             max(stats.cat4wins) as max_cat4wins,
             max(stats.cat5wins) as max_cat5wins
      from stats
     ) smax
     on s.cat1wins = smax.max_cat1wins or
        s.cat2wins = smax.max_cat2wins or
        s.cat3wins = smax.max_cat3wins or
        s.cat4wins = smax.max_cat4wins or
        s.cat5wins = smax.max_cat5wins join
     login l
     on s.login_id = l.login_id;
```

There are two important differences in doing it this way, compared to your original five queries.  First, if someone is tops in two or more categories, they only appear once here.  Second, if mutliple people are tied for the best in one category, all are included.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer....this part of the gallery actually only has room for one user photo per category. I will study this method before I implement any solution.

Comment: I edited the result set to return the first category where the user is the winner.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

**getting userid for each max categories**

What about this? this has no `GROUP BY` and needs just 1 full scan.

```
    SELECT
        IF(cat1wins >= @mxc1, @mxu1 := login_id, @mxu1) AS userid1,
        IF(cat1wins >= @mxc1, @mxc1 := cat1wins, @mxc1) AS max_cat1wins,

        IF(cat2wins >= @mxc2, @mxu2 := login_id, @mxu2) AS userid2,
        IF(cat2wins >= @mxc2, @mxc2 := cat2wins, @mxc2) AS max_cat2wins,

        IF(cat3wins >= @mxc3, @mxu3 := login_id, @mxu3) AS userid3,
        IF(cat3wins >= @mxc3, @mxc3 := cat3wins, @mxc3) AS max_cat3wins,

        IF(cat4wins >= @mxc4, @mxu4 := login_id, @mxu4) AS userid4,
        IF(cat4wins >= @mxc4, @mxc4 := cat4wins, @mxc4) AS max_cat4wins,

        IF(cat5wins >= @mxc5, @mxu5 := login_id, @mxu5) AS userid5,
        IF(cat5wins >= @mxc5, @mxc5 := cat5wins, @mxc5) AS max_cat5wins
    FROM stats, (
        SELECT
          @mxc1 := 0, @mxc2 := 0, @mxc3 := 0, @mxc4 := 0, @mxc5 := 0,
          @mxu1 := 0, @mxu2 := 0, @mxu3 := 0, @mxu4 := 0, @mxu5 := 0
    ) x;
```

**finally we get login information using join with login table**

Please note that following query returns 1~5 records. (1 for all max user are same. 5 for each max user are diffrent)

```
SELECT
    y.*, login.login_id, login.user, login.picture, login.statement,
    IF(y.userid1 = login.login_id, max_cat1wins, NULL) AS max1,
    IF(y.userid2 = login.login_id, max_cat2wins, NULL) AS max2,
    IF(y.userid3 = login.login_id, max_cat3wins, NULL) AS max3,
    IF(y.userid4 = login.login_id, max_cat4wins, NULL) AS max4,
    IF(y.userid5 = login.login_id, max_cat5wins, NULL) AS max5
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        IF(cat1wins >= @mxc1, @mxu1 := login_id, @mxu1) AS userid1,
        IF(cat1wins >= @mxc1, @mxc1 := cat1wins, @mxc1) AS max_cat1wins,

        IF(cat2wins >= @mxc2, @mxu2 := login_id, @mxu2) AS userid2,
        IF(cat2wins >= @mxc2, @mxc2 := cat2wins, @mxc2) AS max_cat2wins,

        IF(cat3wins >= @mxc3, @mxu3 := login_id, @mxu3) AS userid3,
        IF(cat3wins >= @mxc3, @mxc3 := cat3wins, @mxc3) AS max_cat3wins,

        IF(cat4wins >= @mxc4, @mxu4 := login_id, @mxu4) AS userid4,
        IF(cat4wins >= @mxc4, @mxc4 := cat4wins, @mxc4) AS max_cat4wins,

        IF(cat5wins >= @mxc5, @mxu5 := login_id, @mxu5) AS userid5,
        IF(cat5wins >= @mxc5, @mxc5 := cat5wins, @mxc5) AS max_cat5wins
    FROM stats, (
        SELECT
          @mxc1 := 0, @mxc2 := 0, @mxc3 := 0, @mxc4 := 0, @mxc5 := 0,
          @mxu1 := 0, @mxu2 := 0, @mxu3 := 0, @mxu4 := 0, @mxu5 := 0
    ) x
) y INNER JOIN login
WHERE login.login_id IN (userid1, userid2, userid3, userid4, userid5);
```

Comment: That's going to give him multiple rows (one for each user). I think he's looking for the top user for each stat.